Having problems with using 'LIKE' syntax and also the '%'
I am starting a MySQL course and realize some problems with the 'like' syntax and the '%' mark. I am very grateful for your reply. More specifically, the task asking me to 'get all the supporting role winners'.
Here is the tutor's syntax:
SELECT
  *
FROM
   tutorial.oscar_nominees
WHERE
  category = 'actress in a supporting role'
      OR category = 'actor in a supporting role'
    AND winner = 'true'`

My syntax:
SELECT
  *
FROM
   tutorial.oscar_nominees
WHERE
   category LIKE '%supporting%'
    AND winner = 'true'`

The difference between 2 syntaxes is that my syntax only return 1 row even if there are 5 rows that meet certain condition:
Tutor syntax returns:
6 results meet the condition of 'supporting role' in 1936, 5 for actress, 1 for actor
My syntax return:
Only 2 results meet the condition of 'supporting role', 1 for actress, and 1 for actor.
Clearly that my syntax has eliminated duplicates and thus, return on 1 result of 'actress'
